# Parameter for Sybase Sql Anywhere 12 Serverport

Tags: sybase

If SQL Server Anywhere is started via "dbsrv12.exe -z -x tcpip " it opens a Serverport.

Default is 2638.

If more then one database is opened, the other ones are getting "some" serverports.

How could I say: open the server on "this" port

In help of SQL anywhere I find:
TCP/IP: Broadcast, BroadcastListener, DoBroadcast, Host, LDAP, LocalOnly, MyIP, ReceiveBufferSize, SendBufferSize, ServerPort, TDS, Timeout

Using `dbsrv12.exe -z -x tcpip ServerPort 54382` gives 2 errors, that ServerPort and 54382 are not a file.

http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/serverport-network-conparm.html states that:

> You can specify a single port number, or a combination of individual
>   port numbers and     ranges of port numbers. When you specify a list
>   and/or range of port numbers, the database server attempts to bind to
>   all specified port numbers.  For example: (port=1234)
>
> Default  TCP/IP   2638

Therfore i tried `dbsrv12.exe -z -x tcpip (port=54382)` and `dbsrv12.exe -z -x tcpip 54382`, both giving the same error as above.

In which way do I misunderstand the help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax is:

```
dbsrv12.exe -z -x tcpip(ServerPort=54382)
```

No space between `tcpip` and the `(`. You can use "Port=" instead of "ServerPort=" if you want.

Comment: thx, was just overlooking the space. this made the batch a lot easier which fires up a few databases (try to synchronize them by code)